# How to solve this problem that appears in Imo 1982

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

As far as I know this is appear in Imo 1982 and 23rd Vietnam Olympiad (1985).

Find all real values of parameter "a" for which the equation in $ 16x^4 −ax^3 +(2a+17)x^2 −ax+16=0 $ has four solutions which form an geometric progression( the original was arithmetic )

For me, I let r as the first root so the other roots are $ rq, rq^2, rq^3 $ then I put them in the equation, but I don't know where I should I go next. I try the solution from the web too but it is too hard to understand. Please kindly solve this problem for me. Thanks

Comment: Your conjectured roots form a *geometric* progression, contrary to the problem statement.

Comment: *Arithmetic progression* or a *geometric progression*?

Comment: You did observe that the polynomial is palindromic?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry I forgot to change it. My teacher change from arithmetic to geometric to make it more difficult

Comment: If the zeros form a geometric progression, then combining that with the fact that the polynomial is palindromic means that $rq^3=1/r$ and $rq^2=1/(rq)$. It follows that for some parameter $t$ we have $r=t^{-3}, q=t^2$, and the zeros are $t^{-3},t^{-1},t,t^3$. I would first check where this leads...

Answer (score 2):

The roots have product $1$, so are of the form $k^{\pm1},\, k^{\pm3}$ (where without loss of generality $|k|\ge1$) so $\frac{a}{16}=k+k^{-1}+k^3+k^{-3}$. Write $t:=k+k^{-1}$ so $\frac{a}{16}=t(t^2-2)$. The $x^2$ coefficient gives

$$2t^3-4t+\frac{17}{16}=\frac{a}{8}+\frac{17}{16}=(k+k^{-1})(k^3+k^{-3})+2=t^2(t^2-3)+2,$$which rearranges to $$t^4-2t^3-3t^2+4t+\frac{15}{16}=0\implies t\in\left\{-\frac{3}{2},\,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\,\frac{5}{2}\right\}.$$For real progressions $|k+k^{-1}|\ge2$, so$$t=\frac52\implies k=2\implies a=16\left(\frac18+\frac12+2+8\right)=170.$$Other values of $t$ give complex $k$, with $a=16t(t^2-2)$:$$t=-\frac32\implies a=-6,\,t=\frac12\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\implies a=-2\mp6\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Promising. But $|k+k^{-1}|\ge2$ is true only when $k$ is real. I don't think that is necessarily the case here. For example, if $k=e^{i\phi}$, $\phi$ real, then $k+k^{-1}=2\cos\phi\in[-2,2]$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks; fixed.

Comment: Appreciated. The +1 was already there.